# Save kafka broker ids (zookeeper-shell.sh result) to variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to check if broker id is already in use, but I want to do this within a script.

```
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"
```

Gives the result I want, but how would I save this to a variable for later use? What I'm interested in is the actual result of the "ls ..". The whole output includes some fodder:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
Node does not exist: /brokers/ids
```

If I save the result to a variable I actually only get this fodder and the last line is only printed to the screen.

```
var=$(./opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids")
```

And then echo $var gives

```
Connecting to localhost:2181 Welcome to ZooKeeper! JLine support is disabled WATCHER:: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
```

How would I get the actual result of the request to a variable for later use?

Comment: hum.. if I understood what you want is the broker id list that is printed in the last line of the output of the command you give right? I mean this command as far as I can remember returns an array with ids of all brokers, like: [0,1,2] . Is this what you want as a variable?

Comment: Yes, or if none are up then the variable is set to "Node does not exist: /brokers/ids" which is what it returns in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last line of the output using:

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids" | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the script, if someone has a way to make use of the script still, that would be appreciated, but how I ended up doing it:

```
brokerIDs=$(echo dump | nc localhost 2181 | grep brokers/ids | sed 's/\/brokers\/ids\///')
```

And then to check

```
if echo ${brokerIDs[@]} | grep -q -w $newNodeBrokerId; 
then      
    echo "Broker with that id already up";
else      
    echo "Starting Kafka"; 
    # Start kafka service here
fi
```